# Create url on the fly

Tags: jquery

I have some pages with a p tag

```
Page 1:     <p id="cat-one"></p>

Page 2:    <p id="cat-two"></p>

Page 3:   <p id="cat-one"></p>
```

and so on.

I have to first examine the para in the page and create a url dynamically and insert it into the para, depending on which category it belongs to.

```
Eg: cat-one
url  <a href="http://sdsdsad.com" target="_blank" />

cat-two
url  <a href="http://vbccvbcv.com" target="_blank" />

cat-three
url  <a href="http://ohgdssas.com" target="_blank" />
```

and so on.

This is what I have done

```
 var newLink = $('<a href="sdfdsfsdf.html" target="_blank"'>SomeText</a>');
    $("#cat-one").append(newLink);
```

however no idea who to check each para in an article and dynamically generate url;s

Answer (score 0):

you mean 600 html pages or 600 page elements inside one html-document?
if second - then you could do like this - http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/MeF4t/8/

Comment: 600 html pages but then since there are only 12 categories, around 50 pages each have the same category. I have to read the id of the para inside each page and create the url dynamically

Comment: you're going to use jquery as a crawl bot to go through your pages? probably much better solution will be php script with CURL functions